# How to use FormData for AJAX file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

This is my HTML which I'm generating dynamically using drag and drop functionality.

```
<form method="POST" id="contact" name="13" class="form-horizontal wpc_contact" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <div id="legend" class="">
        <legend class="">file demoe 1</legend>
        <div id="alert-message" class="alert hidden"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <!-- Text input-->
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Text input</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge" name="name">
            <p class="help-block" style="display:none;">text_input</p>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">  </div>
        <label class="control-label">File Button</label>

        <!-- File Upload --> 
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-file" id="fileInput" type="file" name="file">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">    

        <!-- Button --> 
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $('.wpc_contact').submit(function(event){
        var formname = $('.wpc_contact').attr('name');
        var form = $('.wpc_contact').serialize();               
        var FormData = new FormData($(form)[1]);

        $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>'+'/wpc-contact-form/resources/js/tinymce.php',
            data : {form:form,formname:formname,ipadd:ipadd,FormData:FormData},
            type : 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success : function(data){
            alert(data); 
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: You should read this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) the `formData();` append method has an optional third parameter for a file.

Answer (score 579, accepted):

For correct form data usage you need to do 2 steps.

**Preparations**

You can give your whole form to FormData() for processing

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

or specify exact data for FormData()

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Attach file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

**Sending form**

Ajax request with jquery will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

After this it will send ajax request like you submit regular form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Update: This request cannot work without `type:"POST"` in options since all files must be sent via POST request.

**Note:**  `contentType: false` only available [from jQuery 1.6 onwards](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Can I set the "enctype" in the Ajax call? I think I may have an issue with it. Or, can I set it on the FormData object?

Comment: You can. For this see lines after THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING in my code.

Comment: @Spell How get data in controller? Do need send `getCsrfToken`?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов This is depends of what type of controller you use. Is it server side or front side controller? You trying to solve CSRF protection here?

Comment: How are the file contents actually read? The contents are not in the event object from the File Input. Is the FileReader being used invisibly in the background?

Comment: That is browser side question. You give one internal object into another. And when you send request, formdata converts from js object to http formatted request

Comment: Can you add more stuff to the $_FILES elements? a "file" entry has some basic info, like `name`, `tmp_name` etc - can you add more? I ended up using $_POST.

Comment: @Buffalo `$_FILES` array generates by php server. You cannot change it outside of your script. All you can do - you can upload as many files as server accepts and it will filled for your server script in `$_FILES`. If you want to add some other staff - you need to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` data

Comment: Yeah, I saw that :( it's kind of lame.

Comment: If you need to get the form by id, i.e. $('#formid'), you need to use $('#formid')[0]. Ex: var formData = new FormData($('#formid')[0]);

Comment: Yup. Or any other jquery support type of ids. eg: `$('div#parent_block_id form[name=form_name]')`

Comment: `var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);`
gives me a null value even on the browser
any ideas?

Comment: @Paulo probably some problems with selector?

Comment: Why do we need to use `var form = $('form')[0];` why not use `var form = $('form');` ? I get it that  `$('form')[0];` gives me the complete HTML form but why is it needed?

Comment: @ManthanJamdagni When you get `$('form')`, it will return jQuery object. But we need regular js object here without jQuery functionality. That's why we get regular object with `[0]` notation. Instead of this construction you can call `document.getElementById()` or simular call.

Comment: Why `new FormData(form);` returns an empty object inspite my form having many input fields with values?

Comment: @van_folmert it isn't actually empty. You can call ::get() or ::getAll() with a key parameter and it will return the value from the form. It looks like empty because it is an internal browser functionality.

Here i show how to make a ajax call with a custom inputs.

Comment: Regarding "all files must be sent via POST request": Can HTTP PUT be used instead of POST?

Comment: What are the `'section'` and `'action'` lines for? Are those required? (They don't seem to correspond to anything in the OP?)

Comment: I used it and I have some problems when I use it on mobile chrome browsers with Android. Any solution?

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but have server issues. Server side PHP-script, which handles the upload, has `$_FILES` array always empty. What could be a reason?

Comment: Issue was jQuery version, it was too old. Thanks for metioned this in answer!

Comment: this worked great, except that I am not getting a response from the request. anyone know why?

Answer (score 44):

I can't add a comment above as I do not have enough reputation, but the above answer was nearly perfect for me, except I had to add

type: "POST"

to the .ajax call. I was scratching my head for a few minutes trying to figure out what I had done wrong, that's all it needed and works a treat. So this is the whole snippet:

Full credit to the answer above me, this is just a small tweak to that. This is just in case anyone else gets stuck and can't see the obvious.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: "POST", //ADDED THIS LINE
    // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    // ... Other options like success and etc
})
```

Answer (score 28):

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

jQuery with CodeIgniter file upload:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);

formData.append('tax_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "member/upload/",
    data: formData,
    //use contentType, processData for sure.
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.modal .ajax_data').prepend('<img src="' +
            base_url +
            '"asset/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        //$(".modal .ajax_data").html("<pre>Hold on...</pre>");
        $(".modal").modal("show");
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        $(".modal .ajax_data").html("<pre>" + msg +
            "</pre>");
        $('#close').hide();
    },
    error: function() {
        $(".modal .ajax_data").html(
            "<pre>Sorry! Couldn't process your request.</pre>"
        ); // 
        $('#done').hide();
    }
});
```

you can use.

```
var form = $('form')[0]; 
var formData = new FormData(form);     
formData.append('tax_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

or

```
var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);
formData.append('tax_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Both will work.

Comment: If we are getting dom with id, why we need to type 0 zero like $(#formId)[0] ?

Comment: @26vivek only the jQuery developers would know the answer to that question.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit_btn").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
        data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "upload.php",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log();
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use the native javascript to find the element by id like: ***document.getElementById("yourFormElementID")***.

```
$.ajax( {
      url: "http://yourlocationtopost/",
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormElementID")),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    } ).done(function(d) {
           console.log('done');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form-withdraw').submit(function(event) {

    //prevent the form from submitting by default
    event.preventDefault();



    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'function/ajax/topup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
          if(returndata == 'success')
          {
            swal({
              title: "Great",
              text: "Your Form has Been Transfer, We will comfirm the amount you reload in 3 hours",
              type: "success",
              showCancelButton: false,
              confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
              confirmButtonText: "OK",
              closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function(){
              window.location.href = '/transaction.php';
            });
          }

          else if(returndata == 'Offline')
          {
              sweetAlert("Offline", "Please use other payment method", "error");
          }
        }
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View:
<label class="btn btn-info btn-file">
Import <input type="file" style="display: none;">
</label>
<Script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
                    var fileUpload = $(this).get(0);
                    var files = fileUpload.files;
                    var bid = 0;
                    if (files.length != 0) {
                        var data = new FormData();
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
                            data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            xhr: function () {
                                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                                    console.log(Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + '%');
                                };
                                return xhr;
                            },
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: data,
                            url: '/ControllerX/' + bid,
                            success: function (response) {
                                location.href = 'xxx/Index/';
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
</Script>
Controller:
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ControllerX(string id)
        {
            var files = Request.Form.Files;
...
```

Comment: It is normally considered good form to provide an explanation along with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually The documentation shows that you can use `XMLHttpRequest().send()`
to simply send  **multiform data**
 in case jquery sucks

Answer (score -7):

Good morning.

I was have the same problem with upload of multiple images. Solution was more simple than I had imagined: include [] in the name field.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

I did not make any modification on FormData.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem the question is asking about and is just a peculiarity of how PHP handles form data with multiple values that have the same name.